# AttributeError:'int' object has no attribute 'iloc' reading a text file with multiple tables Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a text file containing multiple tables and convert them to separate data frames. There is space between each table and they have names. I am trying what seemed like a good solution but getting this AttributeError. Can anyone explain why 'i' variable is being assigned as an int? Where in the code should I be trying to convert to string (if this is in fact the solution?).

```
import pandas as pd
import re 
from IPython.display import display 


file = ('/data/TB/reporting/18RF0375-MI-TBWGS-NextSeq-2019-63_S54_summary.txt')
dfs = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\n\n', header = None, skip_blank_lines=False)

for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    dfs[i] = df [1:]

for df in dfs:
    print(df.head())
```

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 10
7 dfs = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\n\n', header = None, skip_blank_lines=False)
9 for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
---> 10     df.columns = df.iloc[0]
11     dfs[i] = df [1:]
13 for df in dfs:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: I don't think that `read_csv()` can read multiple DataFrames, you need to split the input files first.

Answer (score 0):

The `pd.read_csv` function can only load a CSV file at a time and convert it into `ONE` DataFrame.

`df` in your code is the column index(int).

Below code snippet is helpful to understand it.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = """31DEC,9999
31DEC,2000

31DEC,2001
"""
dfs = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header = None, skip_blank_lines=False)
print(dfs)
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    print(i, df, type(df))
print('-' * 10)
data = """
Day,Year
31DEC,9999
31DEC,2000

31DEC,2001
"""
dfs = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
print(dfs)
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    print(i, df, type(df))
```

**Output**

```
       0       1                                                                                        
0  31DEC  9999.0                                                                                        
1  31DEC  2000.0                                                                                        
2    NaN     NaN                                                                                        
3  31DEC  2001.0                                                                                        
0 0 <class 'int'>                                                                                       
1 1 <class 'int'>                                                                                       
----------                                                                                              
     Day  Year                                                                                          
0  31DEC  9999                                                                                          
1  31DEC  2000                                                                                          
2  31DEC  2001                                                                                          
0 Day <class 'str'>                                                                                     
1 Year <class 'str'>
```